# Assigning highest value in Windows batch script

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, scripting

So I was asked to write a batch script where the user inputs two separate numbers and then I have to output which is higher.  I completed that part with:

```
@echo off
set /p x=Enter a number
set /p y=Enter a second number
if %x% gtr %y% (echo %x% is greater than %y%) else (echo %y% is greater than or equal to %x%)
```

Now I have to modify the program so that instead of the two echo statements, the if-then-else sets z to be whichever value is larger (e.g., set z=%x%).  Add the statement echo %z% is larger as the last instruction in the script.

Can anyone assist with this?  I don't know how to make z equal the higher of the two numbers.

Comment: well, you know how to branch, so the only question is how to replace `echo` with `set`. Have you tried doing the obvious thing yet?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set /p "x=Enter a number : "
set /p "y=Enter a second number : "
if %x% gtr %y% (set Greater=%x%) else (set Greater=%y%)

echo The Greater value is : %Greater%
```